# Why does my python3.8 environment call python 3.7?

Tags: python, centos, conda

I created a conda environment:

```
conda create -n py385 python=3.8.5
```

Now check:

```
$ which python
~/miniconda3/envs/py385/bin/python
(py385) [congmin@localhost spbo]$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

It's all right with 3.8.5 installed. However, when I compile a cython package it failed and it shows that it is using Python 3.7 to compile, instead of python 3.8. What caused this? It should use python 3.8 to compile, since I am in the same environment as python 3.8.5:

```
sudo python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Cythonizing sources
Processing token.pyx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 840, in setuptools_main
    return main(command_line = 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 858, in main
    result = compile(sources, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 780, in compile
    return compile_multiple(source, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 750, in compile_multiple
    context = options.create_context()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 597, in create_context
    self.cplus, self.language_level, options=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 80, in __init__
    from . import Builtin, CythonScope
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/CythonScope.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .UtilityCode import CythonUtilityCode
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/UtilityCode.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .TreeFragment import parse_from_strings, StringParseContext
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/TreeFragment.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .Visitor import VisitorTransform
  File "Cython/Compiler/Visitor.py", line 12, in init Cython.Compiler.Visitor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 40, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 35, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "token.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.tokens.token
    # cython: infer_types=True
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    from . import _pickle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/random/_pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .mtrand import RandomState
  File "_bit_generator.pxd", line 14, in init numpy.random.mtrand
  File "_bit_generator.pyx", line 255, in init numpy.random._bit_generator
AttributeError: type object 'numpy.random._bit_generator.SeedSequence' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data0/spbo/bin/cythonize.py", line 60, in process_pyx
    ["cython"] + flags + ["-o", tofile, fromfile], env=os.environ
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 323, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cython': 'cython'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data0/spbo/bin/cythonize.py", line 169, in <module>
    run(args.root)
  File "/data0/spbo/bin/cythonize.py", line 158, in run
    process(base, filename, db)
  File "/data0/spbo/bin/cythonize.py", line 124, in process
    preserve_cwd(base, process_pyx, root + ".pyx", root + ".cpp")
  File "/data0/spbo/bin/cythonize.py", line 87, in preserve_cwd
    func(*args)
  File "/data0/spbo/bin/cythonize.py", line 78, in process_pyx
    raise Exception("Cython failed")
Exception: Cython failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 199, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 187, in setup_package
    generate_cython(root, "spacy")
  File "setup.py", line 114, in generate_cython
    raise RuntimeError("Running cythonize failed")
RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed
```

I think python3.7 doesn't have cython installed and I need to use python3.8. The question is, why doesn't it use python3.8, which is my current environment?

I am working on Centos3.7.

Comment: @Kaz, could you be more explicit?

Comment: You are using a Cython Installed with your 3.7 interpreter, it seems like.

Comment: Did you install Cython with your 3.8 environment? I'd do that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I installed by 'conda install -c anaconda cython' and got this:  python -c "from Cython.Compiler.Version import version; print(version)"
0.29.21
. But the same error message occurred.